# Can troops and equipment abilities be used on another player's lane?

Tags: xenoshyft-onslaught

In XenoShyft Onslaught, can Troop Card and Equipment Card abilities be used on another player's lane? For example, can a player use the "Stormtrooper" ability to deal 2 damage to a monster on another player's lane?

For references, the rulebook says that player can use card abilities during the "Reaction phase" after revealing an enemy, but nothing about restricting targets:

> - At this time all players have a chance to react to the revealed
>     Enemy. This includes using Special Abilities on their cards or
>     playing Instant cards from their hand.

The "Stormtrooper" card:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the official FAQ (not included in the box published by EDGE) published on CMON website (game creator) : https://cmon.com/product/xenoshyft/xenoshyft-onslaught

> Q: Can I use effects on other player’s lanes (such as the Storm
>   Trooper)?
>   A: Unless a card specifies “this lane” or “your lane” it can be
>   used on any player’s lane

Since the Stormtrooper ability is "Once per round, this troop may deal 2 damage to 1 revealed enemy", it can indeed be used on another player lane.